# why we should not use static and abstract for a single method?

Tags: java

why we should not use static and abstract for a single method?

Comment: Wha? We need a little more definition here.

Comment: Justin I think he / she means why cant you have something that is static and abstract as a function signature at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the static keyword is defined so that a method can be called by a class name rather then an object.  that means the method has to have some sort of definition.  but abstract means you do not have any details about what the method does, it is as it says `**Abstract**`.  When you inherit or extend a class you can then define the method.

Think of an interface.

If you are asking about having a static method inside of an abstract class, that is a different story.  An abstract class is essentially as mentioned an interface and contains just a template of say functions that you must later on implement by inheriting / extending the class.  Once you extend that class the static method does not come along with it (that is by default unless the access modifier is public / protected).

Comment: "the static keyword is defined so that a method can be called by a class name rather then an object." This somewhat misses the full meaning. A static method belongs to the class itself, not to instances *of* the class.

Comment: @JonH - was that patronizing answer really needed? While your definition was not wrong, matt b's was more precise than yours. I hardly think that means he needs to read up on object oriented programming.

Comment: @JonH - And I'm saying that nothing he said gives any indication that he needs to understand it some more. It makes you look bad when you patronize someone who clearly understands the topic at least as well as you do, if not better. So save your weaselly "sorry you took offense" non-apology - I'm not the one you insulted.

Comment: @JonH - thanks for the petty downvote on an unrelated issue, and the bonus insult. Once again you demonstrate your class and charm. I don't have a vendetta against you, I was just pointing out that you were being rude. You, of course, responded with more rudeness. I shouldn't be surprised, but I guess I read too much into your avatar icon.

Comment: @JonH - Nothing at all is wrong with your avatar. It just led me to make some incorrect assumptions about the quality of your character. I thought you were being unintentionally rude to matt, and would appreciate it if someone pointed it out, giving you an opportunity to correct your mistake. Clearly I was wrong, as now I'm the one who's the target of patronizing remarks. I'll just leave you to it, then.

Comment: One last try: Matt offered a clarification to your point. You rejected his clarification and told him to read up on the subject, thereby implying that Matt's clarification was wrong, and he didn't know as much as he should about the topic. That was both incorrect, and insulting. In addition, "I'm sorry you took offense to it" is not an apology, it's a politician's trick. Call me childish if you want, but I'm not the one doing the name calling here. This thread can stand for itself - I've got nothing more to add to it.

Comment: *shrug* - if someone pointed out to me that something I said could be interpreted as insulting, and I hadn't meant to be insulting, I would just say, "Sorry, I didn't mean to be insulting. Allow me to rephrase." - which is very different from "I'm sorry you were offended." And that would be the end of it. You chose to drag this out, and I wasn't the one making childish insults. I mean really - parrots? But for my part, I am sincerely sorry that I got into this. It has clearly done nobody any good. In future, I will leave you strictly alone.

Answer (score 5):

A **static method is not inherited**. Therefore, making it abstract is a nonsense.

Comment: static methods are inherited.  A static method in abstract class Foo can be called as class method on both Foo and Bar that extends Foo.

Comment: They are only accessible, without prefixing with the name of the superclass. But they are not inherited. Example: you define a method with the same name in the subclass ; an instance of the subclass, while executing a method in the superclass, calls the method without prefix : the superclass method is called! If it was inherited, the redefined method would be used. This proves that the two methods are not related, except by syntaxe.

Answer (score 5):

The abstract keyword means that child classes must override the method - this is (one of the ways) Java supports polymorphism.  If you want to make it so that subclasses cannot override the method you mark it final.  So it would be impossible to have an "abstract final" method since they are the exact opposite of each other.

the static keyword implies final as well - all static method are also final.  Thus it is impossible to have a method that is both static and abstract since you would be able to make a method that is abstract and final.

The reason for static being final is that it is bound to the class instead of the instance.  That means that the compiler looks it up at compile time rather than runtime to determine which method to call.  The reason what it is like that?  Arbitrary decision that the designers of Java made - they could have allowed static method to be overridden but decided not to.  I don't have any particular insight as to why the chose one over the other unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, static+abstract is nonsense in Java.  But there have been (rare) occasions where I've wished I could do just that.

The result I was looking for was basically to say that... "all concrete classes that extent this abstract class (or implement this interface) must provide a static method with this signature."  This capability would allow these classes to provide meta-information about themselves.

Normally I have ended up with an instance method in these cases.  If you stipulate that concrete implementations must support the default (no-arg) constructior, you can do...

```
MyInterface obj = MyClassThatImplementsMyInterface.newInstance();
obj.invokeTheMethodIWishWasBothStaticAndAbstract();
```